# C# get A2 Iso country code from country name

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iso, country-codes

I'm trying to fetch a A2 ISO country code by having a full country name as an input.

For example:

```
 var html = new WebClient().DownloadString("mysite.com");
            HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
            htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);

            var result = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span[@class='mem_loc']").ElementAt(0).InnerText;
```

This will give me an out put for example:

```
Bosnia & Herzegovina

United States

Croatia
```

The input would be like:

```
Bosnia & Herzegovina
```

The outputed country code would be: BA

For United States: US

Croatia: HR

And so on...

What's the best way to do this in C#?

Comment: So you can create a List<String> which hold county name and then loopthorugh each and call fetchcode method .

Comment: @YashveerSingh I don't have the logic for FetchCode, it's just an example.. It can be any other method/class used to derrive this country code from this kind of input =)

Comment: ok but what you need a logic or how call that method efficiently

Comment: @YashveerSingh just the method of how to get a 2 county code for any country in the world by ISO standard, regardless of how its done, any method...

Comment: ok let me update my answer then . but you can get this information from wikipidea list of iso code for each country and then you can save it in DB and use them or do you want it only from web ?

Comment: @YashveerSingh only from web, maybe WikiApi offers this information? Input United States => get result US ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133742/discussion-between-yashveer-singh-and-user987).

Comment: ok let me write something like that

Answer (score 0):

This did it in the end:

```
 var html = new WebClient().DownloadString("mysite.com");
            HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
            htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);

            var result = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span[@class='mem_loc']").ElementAt(0).InnerText;
            var regionFullNames = CultureInfo
                       .GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures)
                       .Select(x => new RegionInfo(x.LCID))
                       ;
            var twoLetterName = Regex.Replace(regionFullNames.FirstOrDefault(
                                   region => region.EnglishName.Contains(result)
                                ).ToString(), "{.*?}","");
```

Provided input: United States

Output: US